# How add Android Support Repository Rev. 36 to Eclipse version Neon release 4.6.0?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Recently I've removed my old Eclipse and download/install new version Neon.

I know I have to download SDK from Android SDK Manager. So I've download some releases which I needed and for "Extra" part could find Android Support Library.
I've checked Obsolete and found it, but I want to use new version of appcompat (24.2.0) which is part of Android Support Repository and I've downloaded, but can not add it by normal way (I think).

So how to add appcompat 24.2.0 into Eclipse?

***Note:***

When I want to import Existing Android code Into Workplace and address it to the appcompat there isn't anything to add, because it's Maven:

C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\Android\m2repository\com\Android\support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0

Comment: Google no longer supports Eclipse. Use an AAR-aware build system (Gradle, Maven) and a matching IDE.

Comment: Eclipse Neon supports Gradle, by the way